# Laravel: get last value (name) inserted

Tags: laravel

```
value="{{ DB::table('clients')
           ->select('name')
           ->where('id', DB::table('clients')->max('id') )->get() }}"
```

what it show; I need to show just the name like: Hana not [{"name":"hana"}]

```
[{"name":"hana"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->get()` returns a Collection, which is a wrapper for Arrays in Laravel. You don't need this when you're only looking for a single record, so replace this with `->first()`. Then, to access the `name` value, use `->name`. So, instead of

```
DB::table('clients')->select('name')->where('id', DB::table('clients')->max('id'))->get()
```

use

```
DB::table('clients')->select('name')->where('id', DB::table('clients')->max('id'))->first()->name
```

Note: You shouldn't be doing queries in a `view`; that's what Controllers are for. For example:

```
// In `ExampleController.php`
public function index(){
  $name = DB::table('clients')->select('name')->where('id', DB::table('clients')->max('id'))->first()->name;

  return view("example")->with(["name" => $name]);
}

// In `example.blade.php`
value="{{ $name }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('clients')->max('id') )->first()->id
```

Comment: I don't need the id ,I need the name . anyway thanks ;)

Comment: @katty Then use `->name` instead of `->id`.

Comment: emmm I got it , thnx @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

```
value="{{ DB::table('clients')
       ->select('name')
       ->where('id', DB::table('clients')->max('id') )->first()->name }}"
```